# Angular(9) Material - span element not receiving value from mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I'm working on a project which implements a custom component to implement [Angular Material's `mat-select`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview). The problem is even though the data/value for select options (`mat-option`) is getting populated correctly in the business logic (.ts file), somehow the `span` element seems to be empty, which in turn causes the dropdown to be rendered blank.

```
<mat-option ... ng-reflect-value="correct value">
  <span class="mat-option-text"> </span>
</mat-option>
```

While the value for this particular option shows up correctly in the `ng-reflect-value` attribute of the `mat-option` element, the `span` which is supposed to render the text for the option is empty.

Would appreciate any help.
PS: I'm using shared multi select component.

---

EDIT - Here are some relevant snippets -

1. This is the template of the custom (reusable) component that has been created to implement Angular material's `mat-select`. It is also being used by other components, and works correctly there. Notice that `mat-option` here does use `value` for bind.

**multiselect.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select [formControl]="optionMultiCtrl" [multiple]="enableCheckbox" (selectionChange)="changeDD(multiSelect)" disableOptionCentering #multiSelect>
    <ngx-mat-select-search 
                          [showToggleAllCheckbox]="enableCheckbox" 
                          (toggleAll)="toggleSelectAll($event)" 
                          [formControl]="optionMultiFilterCtrl"
                          noEntriesFoundLabel="No matches found"
                          placeholderLabel=''
                          ></ngx-mat-select-search>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredMultiOptions | async" [value]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="!optionMultiCtrl.valid && optionMultiCtrl.touched">
    {{ariaLabel}} can not be blank
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

---

2. This is the component I'm currently working on. The `<app-multi-select>` selector refers to the template of the component I described above. The options for the select does correctly get populated (verified by `console.log()`) in the property-binded variable `[data]`.

**summary.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"><b>Plan : </b></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <app-multi-select [data]="Plan" [optionMultiCtrl]="PlanType" (changeDropdown)="onChangeFeatureType($event)"></app-multi-select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

---

3. This is the relevant TypeScript code for this component.

**summary.component.ts**

```
PlanType: FormControl = new FormControl('');

 onChangeFeatureType = (event: Event) => {
        console.log(event.target);// this comes out to be "undefined"
        this.loadData();
    }
```

Comment: you have provide more code, we don't have a crystal ball

Comment: You should provide stackblitz of your code

Comment: You forgotten to add value into the span, try `<span class="mat-option-text">{{value}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're not providing any value to the `span` element.

```html
<mat-option ... ng-reflect-value="correct value">
  <span class="mat-option-text">{{ value }}</span>
</mat-option>
```